# How do you swap a component with another after onclick event?

Tags: reactjs

Below, I have a code that is eventually rendered as a route in a react, single page, app. What I was hoping to get, was that depending on what div was clicked, each applying a 'filter', that the component variable, will change components, based off what was imported.

```js
import React from "react";
import { useState } from 'react';
import UpperLevel from "./UpperLevel";
import Grid from "./Grid";
import GridCardio from "./GridCardio";
import GridHome from "./GridHome";
import GridGym from "./GridGym";
import GridUpper from "./GridUpper";
import GridLower from "./GridLower";

const marginAuto = {
  margin: "auto"
};
const cursorPointer = {
  cursor: "pointer"
};
function ExercisesLauncher() {
  const component=<Grid/>;
  function applyCardio() {
  const component=<GridCardio/>
  }
  function applyGym() {
  alert( "GymClicked" );
  }
  function applyHome() {
  alert( "HomeClicked" );
  }
  function applyUpper() {
  alert( "UpperClicked" );
  }
  function applyLower() {
   alert( "LowerClicked" );
  }

  return (<main>
    <section class="colored-section" id="title">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="container-fluid main-text">
            <h1 class="big-heading">Exercises</h1>
            <p>
              Below, feel free to navigate to whatever execrises you may find useful for your next workout. Either learn more about the exercise, or add it to your catelog to later add to your scheduler.
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <h2 class="normal-heading mb-4">Group</h2>
        <div class="container-fluid row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 mb-3 text-center" style={marginAuto}>
          <div id="Gym" onClick={applyGym} class="col-lg-6 d-flex align-items-stretch">
            <div style={cursorPointer} class="card w-100 mb-4 rounded-3 shadow-sm filter">
              <div class="card-heading py-1">
                <h1 class="normal-heading">Gym</h1>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <p>You have equipment that is found at an ordinary gym.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div id="Home" onClick={applyHome} class="col-lg-6 d-flex align-items-stretch">
            <div style={cursorPointer} class="card w-100 mb-4 rounded-3 shadow-sm filter">
              <div class="card-heading py-1">
                <h1 class="normal-heading">At Home</h1>
              </div>
              <div class="card-body">
                <p>
                  Small, mobile, or convenient equipment that still has use.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <h2 class="normal-heading mb-4">Equipment</h2>
        <div class="container-fluid row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 mb-3 text-center" style={marginAuto}>
          <div id="Upper" onClick={applyUpper} class="col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-stretch">
            <div style={cursorPointer} class="card w-100 mb-4 rounded-3 shadow-sm filter">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h1 class="normal-heading">Upper Body</h1>
                <p>
                  Includes the chest, arms, shoulders, and anything else above the waist.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="Lower" onClick={applyLower} class="col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-stretch">
            <div style={cursorPointer} class="card w-100 mb-4 rounded-3 shadow-sm filter">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h1 class="normal-heading">Lower Body</h1>
                <p>
                  Includes the quadriceps, hamstrings, glutes, and anything else below the waist.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div id="Cardio" onClick={applyCardio} class="col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-stretch">
            <div style={cursorPointer} class="card w-100 mb-4 rounded-3 shadow-sm filter">
              <div class="card-body">
                <h1 class="normal-heading">Cardio</h1>
                <p>
                  Any exercise that benefits the cardio-system that gets the heart pumpin.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <section>
      <div class="album py-5 black-section">
        <div id="root" class="container">
          //THIS WILL CHANGE BASED ON CLICKS
          {component};
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

    <footer id="footer">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <a href="index.html">
          {" "}
          <img class="logo mb-3" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fabianenavarro/Get-a-Grip/main/public/images/fist.png" alt=""/>
        </a>
        <p>2022 Getta Grip! LLC</p>
      </div>
    </footer>

  </main>);
}

export default ExercisesLauncher;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

So far, I added alerts to make sure the server recognized these div elements being clicked, now, I just wish to apply the respective component to the body after a div is clicked. The main grid component does load where {component} is, which is perfect, I just do not know why the GridCardio component is not switching out the Grid component

Comment: Why are you re-declaring component in your applyCardio function? Also, if you intend to change the value in the applyXXX function why is the initial declaration const?

Comment: I did not realize I was using const. Anywho, I thought redeclaring component in apply Cardio, would change it's value that is called inside of the "root" div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're tripping up on the way you're using your component variable. You don't want to re-declare the variable, you just want to assign a new value

```
function ExercisesLauncher() {
   var component=<Grid/>;

   function applyCardio() {
       component=<GridCardio/>;
   }

   ...
```

Comment: That makes perfect sense, unfortunately, my grid is not displaying the way I would like it to. Would you sense where else the bug could be occurring?

Comment: I don't know what 'not displaying the way I would like it to' means. If you're getting an error or some new behavior you need help with I suggest detailing it in another question.

Comment: Essentially, I am feeding an array of objects into a component, each of which contains values from each object. The grids being applied each have a certain value. CardioGrid component only shows objects with "cardio" and etc.,  a filter essentially.

Comment: Hello, I am not sure if it is worth your time, but I was able to use your solution and come up with my own, thank you for pointing me in the right direction! I have it posted below if you are curious to see what I devised.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than loading Grid into a component, that is loaded into another component, I used in my App2 to load the page(compiled everything pertaining to this page) and came up with this script, which was a lot easier than I thought it would be. I learned that I **had** to rerender my components! This does exactly what I needed! I had a lot of unnecessary components and this was the best approach in my opinion. I am also trying to get my mind used to using arrow notation, so do not mind the "function's

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import {render} from 'react-dom';
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar";
import Grid from "./components/Exercises/Grid";
import GridCardio from "./components/Exercises/GridCardio";
import GridHome from "./components/Exercises/GridHome";
import GridGym from "./components/Exercises/GridGym";
import GridUpper from "./components/Exercises/GridUpper";
import GridLower from "./components/Exercises/GridLower";

const marginAuto = {
  margin: "auto"
};
const cursorPointer = {
  cursor: "pointer"
};

//THIS IS ALL RESPONSIBLE FOR LOADING EVERYTHING IN ONE PAGE DONT WORRY ABOUT IT
function App2() {
  // const [display, setState] = React.useState(<Grid/>);
  let component = <Grid/>;
  const [gridState, changePlease] = useState(component);

  function applyHome(){
    changePlease(<GridHome/>);
  }
  function applyCardio(){
    changePlease(<GridCardio/>);
  }
  function applyLower(){
    changePlease(<GridLower/>);
  }
  function applyUpper(){
    changePlease(<GridUpper/>);
  }
  function applyHome(){
    changePlease(<GridHome/>);
  }
  function applyGym(){
    changePlease(<GridGym/>);
  }

  return (<section>
    <NavBar/>

    <main>
      <section class="colored-section" id="title">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="container-fluid main-text">
              <h1 class="big-heading">Exercises</h1>
              <p>
                Below, feel free to navigate to whatever execrises you may find useful for your next workout. Either learn more about the exercise, or add it to your catelog to later add to your scheduler.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>

          <h2 class="normal-heading mb-4">Group</h2>
          <div class="container-fluid row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 mb-3 text-center" style={marginAuto}>
            <div id="Gym" class="col-lg-6 d-flex align-items-stretch">
              <div style={cursorPointer} onClick={applyGym} class="card w-100 mb-4 rounded-3 shadow-sm filter">
                <div class="card-heading py-1">
                  <h1 class="normal-heading">Gym</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                  <p>You have equipment that is found at an ordinary gym.</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

              <div id="Home" class="col-lg-6 d-flex align-items-stretch">
                <div style={cursorPointer} onClick={applyHome}  class="card w-100 mb-4 rounded-3 shadow-sm filter">
                  <div class="card-heading py-1">
                    <h1 class="normal-heading">At Home</h1>
                  </div>
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <p>
                      Small, mobile, or convenient equipment that still has use.
                    </p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>

          </div>

          <h2 class="normal-heading mb-4">Equipment</h2>
          <div class="container-fluid row row-cols-1 row-cols-md-3 mb-3 text-center" style={marginAuto}>

            <div id="Upper" class="col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-stretch">
              <div style={cursorPointer} onClick={applyUpper}  class="card w-100 mb-4 rounded-3 shadow-sm filter">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h1 class="normal-heading">Upper Body</h1>
                  <p>
                    Includes the chest, arms, shoulders, and anything else above the waist.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div id="Lower" class="col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-stretch">
              <div style={cursorPointer} onClick={applyLower} class="card w-100 mb-4 rounded-3 shadow-sm filter">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h1 class="normal-heading">Lower Body</h1>
                  <p>
                    Includes the quadriceps, hamstrings, glutes, and anything else below the waist.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div id="Cardio" onClick={applyCardio} class="col-lg-4 d-flex align-items-stretch">
              <div style={cursorPointer}  class="card w-100 mb-4 rounded-3 shadow-sm filter">
                <div class="card-body">
                  <h1 class="normal-heading">Cardio</h1>
                  <p>
                    Any exercise that benefits the cardio-system that gets the heart pumpin.
                  </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section>
        <div class="album py-5 black-section">
          <div id="root" class="container">
            {/* THIS WILL CHANGE BASED ON CLICKS */}
             {gridState}
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <footer id="footer">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a href="index.html">
            {" "}
            <img class="logo mb-3" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fabianenavarro/Get-a-Grip/main/public/images/fist.png" alt=""/>
          </a>
          <p>2022 Getta Grip! LLC</p>
        </div>
      </footer>

    </main>);
  </section>);
}

export default App2;
```